# Why is the 2nd season episode "Peak Performance" the only episode of TNG not available on Paramount Plus?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Why is the 2nd season episode "Peak Performance" the only episode of TNG not available on Paramount Plus?

[image]

It can't be for reasons of episode quality...they left "Shades of Gray" in...

(In case this is some regional licensing thing, I am in the USA)

Comment: Hmmm....this question seems familiar, not sure why.

Comment: Possibly streaming rights? - https://www.primetimer.com/item/Paramount-is-missing-a-beloved-Star-Trek-Deep-Space-Nine-episode-due-to-quot-streaming-rights-quot-gASRl1

Comment: @Paulie_D if you look at the referenced tweet, Paramount later says it was a screw-up and fixed it (on the DS9 episode).

Comment: Reddit suggests that episodes are regularly found to be missing and pop back a few days later. For all we know this was another screw up already fixed or in the process of being so.

Comment: ... or https://help.paramountplus.com/s/article/PD-Why-isn-t-the-show-or-episode-I-want-to-stream-available-on-demand

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm looking for a specific reason about this episode, if there is one. "It doesn't work"...I could have written that. But, I will keep checking (it's been a couple of days).

Comment: Perhaps tweet paramount+ for a reason... they seem to have responded before. ☺

Comment: Probably it's some sort of rights issue. The script went through multiple hands and there were shared rights from the old series to the new series because of the presence of an old series ship .

Comment: Either that or just a plain old cockup. Possibly both

Comment: @Valorum that would be interesting, if it was because of the old ship.

Comment: I can't even log in - they may be having larger issues. More likely the file is just missing the appropriate tag in their content management system so it's not appearing. Did you try searching for it explicitly vs in the season overview?

Comment: @NKCampbell yep, did try that. "Can't find peak performance".

Comment: @NKCampbell - [It was there before, but has since been removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRLzv.png)

Comment: I sub to P+ through Amazon Prime and the episode is available to me. It's probably just a bug. Also in the US.

Comment: I have twitted at the official Paramount Plus account. Hopefully they'll respond promptly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 5, 2022, the episode is available.

[image]

Comment: Oh thank goodness.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I can't even remember now why I wanted to watch it back in June.

Comment: To watch Data bust him up.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it was absent

Comment: @Valorum (insert evil laugh) But only I have the power of acceptance! Hahahahaha! Or, consider it a frame challenge.

Comment: Riker’s first command!